# How set NLS_LANG for every connection (ojdbc8)

Tags: java, oracle, nls-lang

I using java application and using ojdbc8 to connecting to DB and
I have a legacy database set with NLS_LANG set to CL8ISO8859P5. This I cannot change.

And i got problem, when i sending data to DB, it`s replacing unknow characters like **«** and **»** to **?**

How i can change NLS_LANG for all connections in app or fix this problome on other way?

Comment: imo, that is not an encoding issue on client side, just ISO 8859-5 encoding does not have those symbols (« and ») - database unable to store them as varchar. Have you any issues with cyrillic symbols?

Comment: Yep, it doesn`t contains it, i have`t any troubles with any "cyrillic symbols"

Comment: Java/JDBC does not use `NLS_LANG`, see [Database JDBC Developer's Guide - Globalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/global.htm#JJDBC28643): *Starting from Oracle Database 10g, the `NLS_LANG` variable is no longer part of the JDBC globalization mechanism. The JDBC driver does not check NLS environment. So, setting it has no effect.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`«` and `»` do not exit in ISO 8859-5 (aka. `CL8ISO8859P5`). If you cannot change the characters set then there is no solution.

Either do not use `«` and `»` or try `NCHAR`/`NVARCHAR2` data type, which typically supports a wider set of characters.